# How to make Eclipse compile with Java 1.5 in Mac OS X Leopard (10.5)?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have been developing in Snow Leopard (10.6).  I believe I have some Java6-only API features and I'd like to find these.  I moved my project to Leopard (10.5) -- since Snow Leopard does not support Java 1.5 -- but I am so far unable to make Eclipse give compile errors for a Java API call which I know to have been added in 1.6.

Here is what I have done: Project properties -> Java Compiler -> set everything to 1.5.  Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> selected JVM 1.5.0.  Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> says JRE System Library [JVM 1.5.0]

What am I missing?  Is there another way to find Java API calls added in 1.6 when using Eclipse in Snow Leopard?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to have SL run Java1.5, I have it but I don't remeber how I did it :P http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/8837/capturadepantalla201004h.png  Ask on http://superuser.com

Comment: I think I downloaded from somewhere and I unzip it and modify the links and that was all.

Comment: Either way, I suspect I'd have the same problem.  At least in Leopard, 1.5 is officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

If JVM 1.5.0 is set as your system library and the compiler settings are at 1.5 then the only other possible problem would be other libraries (non-JVM) that may have 1.6 code and that should just be a matter of checking the library providers documentation as to minimum requirements. The only other check would be if you have unit tests run them in the 1.5 JRE you have installed, or lacking that launch your app using a 1.5 JVM and run it through its paces.